# Loop through folders without recursion

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion

I was looking for an algorithm, so OS is not problem, in how to loop through folders without the use of recursion.

Recursion is not the answer because recursion cannot go to "infinity" and beyond, while a "while loop" can get there.

Programming language doesn't matter.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why is recursion not the answer?

Comment: I was looking for algorithm, so OS is not problem. Recursion is not the answer because recursion cannot go to the "infinity", while "while loop" can go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) data structure for [depth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) traversal. Here is some sample code in C#:

```
    var stack = new Stack<string>();

    stack.Push(@"C:\");

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentDirectory = stack.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("Visiting: " + currentDirectory);

        foreach (var childDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(currentDirectory))
        {
            stack.Push(childDirectory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course, this is just manually duplicating what the compiler would have done for you, if you had used recursion in the first place.