# how can i delete all items under selected item in treeview

Tags: c++, qt

i have treeview as the view and QStandardItemModel as the model.
now i each node in the model has child nodes . my question is
how can i delete all the child nodes under selected item ?
all i found is this but this is for one row . i need all the rows under item.

```
bool TableModel::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        rowList.removeAt(position);
    }

    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove a row from a model, the child rows of that row will also be removed. So you don't need to do anything.

However, it looks like you're implementing your own row storage using QList. In this case, it depends what you've set up--what type your QList is storing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using recursion. You could alter your function so that before it removes an item, it calls itself on each child of that item.

Added:

If you don't want to use recursion, then you could use a stack like in this question:

[Loop through folders without recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178860/loop-through-folders-without-recursion)

Comment: yeah i know this trick with the stack, i wander if there build in Qt way to do it right

Answer (score -1):

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string sql = @"delete tbl_requirements1 where aid = " + int.Parse(treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString()) + "";
                Utils.ExecuteSql(sql);
                DeleteNodes(treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes);
                treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();

        }
        public void DeleteNodes(TreeNodeCollection treeViewNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode myNode in treeViewNode)
            {
                int aid = int.Parse(myNode.Tag.ToString());

                string sql = "delete tbl_requirements1 where aid=" + aid + "";
                Utils.ExecuteSql(sql);

                if (myNode.GetNodeCount(true) > 0)
                {
                    DeleteNodes(myNode.Nodes);
                }

            }
```